# Can sb explain me the uses of se in Spanish

Tags: gramática

I know that there are many form of **se** in Español but can somebody give me the summary of that?

Comment: A similar question: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10602/why-se-in-front-of-some-verbs

Comment: A useful resource: [usos del **se** en español](http://mimosa.pntic.mec.es/ajuan3/lengua/usosdese.htm). "Se" and "que" may be the two most complicated particles in the Spanish language. I think that a proper (exhaustive) answer may exceed the format of this site. If it is just a summary what you want, each section in that article should be enough to guide further research.

Answer (score 3):

Un breve resumen de los usos de la partícula `se` cortesía de [esta web](http://mimosa.pntic.mec.es/ajuan3/lengua/usosdese.htm).

1- Se sustituto de le/les. Función: Complemento Indirecto

> Le di el libro / Se lo di.

2- Se reflexivo: Función: Complemento Directo/Indirecto

> La niña se peina (a sí misma)

3- Se dativo o intensificador del verbo.

> Comió tres platos. / **Se** comió tres platos.

4- Se recíproco

> Las niñas se peinan (la una a la otra)

5- Indicador de voz media

> No se asuste usted.

6- Se pronominal.

> Se arrepintió de lo que había hecho

7- Se impersonal.

> En este restaurante se come muy bien

8- Se pasivo reflejo

> Se venden pisos.

Comment: Nobody marked this question as "too broad" or as "too long for the Q&A format", but no one was answering it either, so I copied some content from a really useful web and posted the answer as community wiki. This way, whoever feels that answer could/should be expanded to include a better explanation is free to do it. Is also up to the community to judge up to which level we want to expand that answer (expanding it would for sure create value for this site but the mission of this site is not to replace or become a text book, so we may need to balance those). Regards.